# UML Number of actors of a Use Case diagram

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

Is it possible for a use case to have more than one actor?
And if it is, do you know of a good reference where I can find that information (book, webpage) because I am having a problem with a diagram I made for a test.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the UML spec allows to use multiple actors an despite the fact that I have used primary and secondary actor(s) in use cases in the past I have come to the conclusion that a use case shall have only a single actor. When you go down to that paradigm you will find that the use case cut is much easier and clearer than when using multiple actors. Please see the following slides that explain this in more detail: http://de.slideshare.net/putchavn/usecase-case-is-a-dialog-not-a-process

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a use case can have associations to multiple actors

The only true source for this information is the UML specification on [uml.org](http://uml.org/)

From UML 2.5 beta2 -> 18.2 Classifier Descriptions -> Actor -> Constraints

> - associations
>
> An Actor can only have Associations to UseCases, Components, and 
>   Classes. Furthermore these Associations must be binary.
>
> ```
> inv: Association.allInstances()->forAll( a |
>    a.memberEnd->collect(type)->includes(self) implies
>    (
>       a.memberEnd->size() = 2 and
>       let actorEnd : Property = a.memberEnd->any(type = self) in
>         actorEnd.opposite.class.oclIsKindOf(UseCase) or
>         ( actorEnd.opposite.class.oclIsKindOf(Class) and not
>           actorEnd.opposite.class.oclIsKindOf(Behavior))
>         )
>    )
> ```

There are no constraints relative to the relation to the actor on the side of the use case

Comment: Of course OMG is the "true source" but unfortunately they are just human. And use cases are not the main expertise of the guys that assembled the UML specs. So I disagree with Superstructures. See also here: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/143183-5976908864220651521